# set firefox window to open in specific position

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, compiz, metacity, wmctrl

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and i want to open firefox window in specific position ,but before calling firefox i need to execute this command `metacity --replaceand` after a second this command : `killall metacity` (for removing title bar in windows), i tried to use `wmctrl` and `compizConfig Setting Manager` application in ubuntu 14.04 for changing window position but both of them don't work in my case,is there any setting in firefox for opening in specific position?